# Problems trying to lay out some XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Look at the following XAML:-

```
<Border Width="200">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
     <TextBlock Text="The quick brown fox jumped"/>
     <TextBlock Text="X"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Currently, as I increase the amount of text in the first textblock, it pushes the second textblock ("X") along, until eventually it gets pushed off the r.h. side of the parent border and disappears from view.

How can I rewrite the XAML so that the "X" still gets pushed along by the first textblock (as its size increases), but only as far as the r.h. edge of the parent. Once this happens I would like the first textblock to be the one that gets truncated instead.

Note that the parent's width will be unknown at runtime (I've only set it to 200 to demonstrate the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh, once again I ask a SO question then figure it out minutes later. Here is the solution:-

```
<Border Width="200">
  <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" LastChildFill="True">
     <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="X"/>
     <TextBlock Text="The quick brown fox"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Border>
```